# What do "that I will" & "dish it" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I'm optimistic and bubbly yet laid back and down to earth. I've definitely got a sense of humor... if you're not laughing you're not living! I try not to take life too seriously.
>
> Fitness is a huge part of my life, my future partner should have a love for fitness as I do. I stay active and am always on the go! I love cooking, a good book and going on adventures. I want to see the world, and **that I will!**
>
> Huge sports fan, especially football. Sunday's are for family and football of course!
>   Also, my family and my faith are everything to me!
>
> I'm a very independent woman, who knows where she is going in life, and I would hope my future partner did as well. As far as what I'm looking for I'd have to say someone who has a positive and happy outlook on life, who can appreciate sarcasm and **dish it** right back.

In the second paragraph, she says: "that I will" , What is the meaning of this phrase? If she means "I will see the world" , what is the use of **that**? **that I will.

In the last paragraph she says **...dish it right back**. What does it mean?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to [see the world], and [see the world] I will!—She wants something, and will try her best to do it. "that I will" is asserting that this is not idle chat.

Answer (score 1):

In the second paragraph ("I want to see the world, and that I will!") the meaning is: "I am very determined to do much travel and see the world."
The "and that I will!" fragment could be re-written as "and I am very certain that I can ensure that this will occur through my efforts!"

In the last paragraph ("who can appreciate sarcasm and dish it right back") the meaning is: "I like the use of sarcasm and I use it myself, particularly when directed at me."

Answer (score 0):

"Dish it (right) back" is idiomatic, and derives the serving up of food by a designated person at a communal meal. This is called "dishing up" and the food is "dished out", that is, placed on plates or dishes. (Also seen as "plating up", but the latter is more posh.)

Hence you "dish out" the same attacks in the form of sarcastic comments as you receive.

The idiom "dish it (right) back" derives from that: whatever gets "dished out" to you, you "dish out" right back.

"Right" in this context is also idiomatic, and means "directly", or "immediately", or "in exactly the same way as it was dished out in the first place".

As for "that I will", that is also idiomatic, and means "I will most certainly do that", and is emphatic.